# Can't send fax with Fax Server on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, fax

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 (ip: 192.168.62.1) which installed Fax Server feature on it and connected with Fax device (ip: 192.168.62.20) via LAN.

I haven't success yet to send fax using Windows App: "Windows Fax and Scan". I am wondering what the problem is. Do we really need dedicated modem?

My fax device is:
[Kyocera FS-C8520MFP](https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/products/product/fsc8520mfp.html)

Thanks in advance

Comment: models please, are you using a multi-function copier??

Comment: yes, kind of. I updated the question @JacobEvans

Comment: did you install the fax driver?

Comment: Yes sir, fax driver only actually. https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/service/dlc.false.driver.FSC8520MFP._.EN.html

Comment: Did you get any error messages on the Windows Server in the event logs when trying to send a fax? Did you get any error messages in the application sending the fax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fax has morphed many times over the years, for windows to use Fax/Scan it will want to use a driver written to interface with Fax/Scan OR a real fax modem.

You can likely print to a fax queue, which is all handled by the Kyocera itself and give windows indication that it is a fax.  You'll need to load the drive on all endpoints you want to fax.

In my experience, hylafax email gateway is a good option or [hosted](http://www.pulsar360.com/p360-fax/) (check compliance requirements)

Comment: Right, I can do print to fax. In short, I can't use the Windows Fax and Scan application now?

Comment: correct, it's up the the driver writer to configure those hooks

Comment: sadly a cheap Brother MFC supports it.

Comment: I see, how do you know it supports or not? So, I can check another models.

Comment: if one model doesn't support it I doubt any do.

Comment: how about Panasonic KX-series? just ask

Comment: no idea bud, maybe read the manual and see how they tell you to send a fax via PC?